# Cypress.io on Chrome with "SameSite by default cookies" issue

Tags: google-chrome, session-cookies, cypress

We're running Cypress.io locally via `http://` using Chrome, and when "SameSite by default cookies" is on (which they are starting to roll out to all users), our login tests fail because the session cookie cannot be set (is blocked because the connection is not secure). Any suggestions on a workaround? I looked into setting a Chrome flag as per:

https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Examples

with flag:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

but couldn't find an appropriate flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by simply changing the session cookie's `samesite` attribute for my local/test environment from `none`, which requires `secure`, to `lax`. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Can you provide an example of where / how you added this? I'm running into the same issue currently. Thanks!

Comment: @emaxsaun it really depends on what programming language you're using and how you create the cookie. With PHP 7 for example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#125242. I have some conditional logic in my app which determines if I'm local, and I set accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @erebus, I was able to figure it out (Using Cypress).

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue.

My solution was going to chrome://flags (after running chrome from cypress) and set SameSite by default cookies to Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually write an interceptor in cypress to rewrite the headers of requests to use SameSite="None". This blog explains how in more detail.

https://www.tomoliver.net/posts/cypress-samesite-problem

This technique is good if you don't have control over the server sending the response. e.g a third party auth server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).